# How to print description of port

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I made a port scanner and I want to give description to the ports. So like printing the port with the description. I was thinking my best bad is to make the description on a file and then print it but I don't know how to do that. Or on the file I could put the port and then the description separate them with a ":", search for that port on the file and get the description.

```
def scan_port(port):
    try:
        timeout = 10.0
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteHost,port)) 
        identify_port()
        if result == 0:
            print(colored("[+] Port {}: Open".format(port), 'green'))
            sock.close()
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working with your current code?

Comment: Take a look at `/etc/services`

Comment: @roganjosh As you can see, his current code doesn't even try to do what he says.

Comment: @Barmar fair enough, but your suggestion wouldn't work with Windows. I'm only trying to get some grounding in the issue. It's as much a tool to prompt them to describe the issue as it is to try solve it.

Comment: There are many places to find copies of /etc/services on the web.

Comment: "my best bad" == "my best bet"?

Comment: I am trying to solve it with the '.readline()' command but I haven't tried it yet because I am not finished. My os is macos so this tool isn't made for windows.

Comment: You can read the file and convert it into a `dict` whose keys are the port numbers.

Comment: Come back when you're finished. Post what you tried and explain the problem you're having with it. There's no point in posting the question until you've gotten that far.

Comment: @Barmar you are right I just saw the file and it's telling me all the ports. I just need to organize it and figure out a way to make the code print the description.

Comment: If you put the information into a dict named `ports`, you can simply print `ports[port]`.

Comment: Yes I renamed the file I just got to write the code there.

Comment: If you could please leave a answer with the code you just described to me I will really appreciate it.